# How to remove items from a NodeList based on their type?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, nodelist

Context: I'm trying to parse an XML file for certain information. For some reason, when I read in the XML, it is reading in the different XML sections 2 times each, once as 'text' and once as the actual XML tag (in my case, 'Transaction').[console log of Nodelist shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deqSs.png)

Here is my code for reading in the XML and my beginning attempt to remove the nodes:

```
  //At this point I have read in the XML file as a big string and passed it to this function
  function parseXML(content) {

  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(content, 'text/xml');

  //access to XML nodes and get node values
  var catalog = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Transactions')[0];


  var cNodes = catalog.childNodes;
  console.log(cNodes); //this console.log shows the data that you see in the picture above

  //Want to loop through child nodes and remove all of type 'text' and just keep the ones of type 'transaction'
  for (var x=0; x < catalog.childNodes.length; x++) {
    if (catalog.childNodes[x].__proto__ == "Text") {
      //want to remove all nodes of type 'text' here

    }
     
  }
```

What I want to do is get rid of the nodes of type 'text' and just keep the 'transaction' nodes. Not quite sure how to do this as I have never done this before. Let me know if you need any more information for my question to make sense. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't show an image of log output: show the log output, with code formatting. And if it's too much output, remember that you're expected to make your code _and_ data be of manageable size (so for the purpose of this question, you probably want to reduce your XML file to a minimal size, while still helping illustrate your needs).

Comment: you can use remove function for nodes you want to remove
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove